# show empty tableview while fetching records from database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have a tableview and on `-(void)tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` i am fetching records from sqlite database and display on another detailViewController's tableview.While fetching records UI get stuck.  I have to show empty `tableView` of detailViewController's on tap of row with activity indicator on that until all records not get fetched from database.But problem is that main run loop gets blocked when i call function to fetched records from database from `-(void)viewDidLoad` of detailViewController's and black screen appears.
I have read somewhere it is not good to perform database operation on background thread.So I can't perform fetching operation on background thread.
What is the best way to solve this problem?

How can i display records while detailViewController's view get updated.Is there any good designPattern or is it right to perform database operation on background thread?Also is it fine to do heavy operation such as database operation in viewDidAppear?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

fetching record from database in **`viewWillAppear`** method and put it into `NSMutableArray` and Check it with `NSLog(@"%@",myMutableArr);` if you got proper data then put on `UITableView`

refere [This Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/) and also [This is official document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

I think loading database on different thread is not a problem. But if you want to update the table view with your database result, use the method, performSelectorOnMainThread. Since UI update should be always in main thread.

Are result from database is need for the table view? or only for the detailView?
If it is only for the detailView, why not you query the database when the detailView will appear?

Comment: yes detailViewController's load its tableview with these results

Comment: Then you can query the database in a separate thread, manage the the thread in viewDidAppear and unload method, and update the tableview time to  time when you read some or all data you needed. I did that and it works perfect in my app https://itunes.apple.com/app/id483162196.